# Argument error while deploying rails app via capistrano to bluehost

Tags: ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

I have build a sample app using rails and trying to deploy it using capistrano to bluehost.
But I am failing to do so. I followed the instructions mentioned in this http://vasil-y.com/2012/08/21/rails-capistrano-git-bluehost/

This is the contents of my config/deploy.rb:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :application, "rails_scaffold"

# BlueHost SSH user
set :user, "username"

# App Domain
set :domain, "example.com"

# We don't need sudo on BlueHost
set :use_sudo, false

# git is our SCM
set :scm, :git

# master is our default git branch
set :branch, "master"

# Use local git repository
set :repository,  "#{domain}:/home/#{user}/rails_apps/#{application}"
set :local_repository, "."

# Checkout, compress and send a local copy
set deploy_via, :copy
set deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/rails_apps/#{application}"

# We have all components of the app on the same server
server domain, :app, :web, :db, :primary => true

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end

  # Touch tmp/restart.txt to tell Phusion Passenger about new version
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path, 'tmp', 'restart.txt')}"
  end
end

# Clean-up old releases
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

But when I run the cap deploy:setup command, I get the following error:

```
/home/swaroop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:22:in `set': invalid variable `/u/apps/rails_scaffold' (variables must begin with an underscore, or a lower-case letter) (ArgumentError)
```

It says the application name must begin with an underscore or lowercase alphabets. And my application name looks like it is valid. 
What am I doin wrong here?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of your `set` calls have arguments which are not symbols:

```
set deploy_via, :copy
set deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/rails_apps/#{application}"
```

Those should be:

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/rails_apps/#{application}"
```

(Note the colons before `deploy_via` and `deploy_to`)

You can see why it might look related to your `:application` variable if we inspect what is happening in the line containing `:deploy_to`: it first calls the `deploy_to` method (since you're missing the colon, it looks like a method call), and `deploy_to` defaults to `"/u/apps/#{application}"` in the [Capistrano source code](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L30):

```
_cset(:deploy_to) { "/u/apps/#{application}" }
```

So really, your code is effectively trying trying to run this:

```
set "/u/apps/#{application}", "/home/#{user}/rails_apps/#{application}"
```

but `"/u/apps/#{application}"` is not a valid variable name in Capistrano. Adding colons to those lines should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will definitely try this out.